# In Smash Up, can you "destroy" a card from your hand?

Tags: smash-up

Here are the definitions from their rulebook located here: [Smash Up Rules](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2012/06/AEG-SU-Rulebook.pdf)

> **Discard**: When a card gets discarded, it goes to the discard pile of the player whose deck it came from, no matter who played or controlled it.
>
> **Destroy**: When a card
>   says to destroy another card, put the destroyed card in its
>   owner’s discard pile.

If I can destroy one of my minions to draw the same number of cards as its power, would I be able to destroy one from my hand? I'm thinking no, but would like to appeal to others who may have broader experience with other games that might use this terminology commonly or might simply know a ruling on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

I don't know if this is explicitly mentioned anywhere in the rules, but destroying a minion refers to destroying a minion card on a base.

This is akin to Magic: The Gathering, which has concepts of discarding cards from one's hand and destroying permanents on the battlefield.

Answer (score 4):

**No**. This has been clarified in [more recent rules](https://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2014/11/SU7_Rulebook.pdf) (pg 9):

> **Destroy:** This lets you remove a card that’s in play and put it in its owner’s discard pile.

Destroy specifically refers to cards *in play*.

Answer (score 3):

In Smash Up, you can only destroy cards that have explicitly been played. Anything in your hand is currently out of play, likewise, to remove anything from your hand would require the keyword "discard" and not "destroy".